# "Function" Is Not Defined

Tags: javascript, slider

Im trying to make a slider that changes images every 5 secondes. But in console it says
"changemementImages is not defined at new slider"

```js
//change images every 5 sec
this.temps = setInterval(changemementImages, 5000);

this.image5Sec = changemementImages =()=>{
    if(this.i >= 2){
        this.i-=3;
        document.getElementById("images").src = this.slide[this.i];
    }
    else if (this.i = 0){
        document.getElementById("images").src = this.slide[++this.i];
    }

}
```

Comment: Cause you use it before you define it?

Comment: Probably because changemementImages is not defined.

Comment: But i defined it on the first line of code. Didnt i ?

Comment: No, you call it in the first line of code. You define it in the 3rd. Your question would be better if it had a more complete working example.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions need to be initialized before using them unlike declared functions.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Try to initialize changemementImages before setInterval.

```
const changemementImages =()=>{
   if(this.i >= 2){
       this.i-=3;
       document.getElementById("images").src = this.slide[this.i];
   }
   else if (this.i = 0){
       document.getElementById("images").src = this.slide[++this.i];
   }

}

this.temps = setInterval(changemementImages, 5000);

this.image5Sec = changemementImages;
```